# how to get all button object defined in android xml laypout file in java like childat()?

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I want to set height of drawable for all buttons upon the height of Button inflated.
and i can get all button objects like this

```
for(int i=0;i<layout.getChildCount();i++)
{
Button b = layout.childAt(i);
b.setHeight(x);
}
```

and my problem here is to get all only buttons inside all nested layouts. In some layouts there are Buttons and textvies too, how can i access to only buttons ?

Can anybody help me out ?

Comment: may i know why you want to do this?

Comment: as i mentioned above, the position of drawable background which is defined in layerlist has to be changed upon height of button.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

added a new class and extended the Button and then override the method whichever you want :)

In my case i override the  setBackgroundDrawable()

```
@Override
public void setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable background) {


Log.d("button","setting new background  ");
Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[5];
Resources resources = getResources();




layers[0] = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.outer_rectangle);
layers[1] = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.inner_rectangle);
layers[2] = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.upper_ovel);
layers[3] = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient_fill);
layers[4] = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.lower_ovel);

LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);

layerDrawable.setLayerInset(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
layerDrawable.setLayerInset(1, 3, 3, 3, 0);
layerDrawable.setLayerInset(2, 3, 15, 3, 25);
layerDrawable.setLayerInset(3, 3, 23, 3, 0);
layerDrawable.setLayerInset(4, 4, 60, 4, -5);



super.setBackgroundDrawable(layerDrawable);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why you would want to do this, but you could try this,

```
for(int i=0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++)
{
    View v = layout.getChildAt(i);
    if (v instanceof Button) {
        Button b = (Button) v;
        b.setHeight(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize Button

```
......
Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myBtn1);
Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myBtn2);
List<Button> btns = new ArrayList<Button>();
btns.add(btn1);
btns.add(btn2);
......
```

Operate the second button

```
int i=2;
btns.get(i).setWidth(100);
btns.get(i).setHeight(100);
```